# VSTO Add-in Works in Office SP3, but not SP2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, office-interop, ms-project

I've developed an MS Project add-in (VS2010, targeting .Net 4) that works swimmingly well on machines that have Office SP3 installed (WinXP, 7).  However, when installed on machines with Office SP2 installed (Win XP), the add-in loads but becomes unresponsive after a few seconds.

When I toggle the add-in in the COM Add-ins Dialog box (after its stopped working), I get this weird messagebox:

```
"Com object that has been seperated from its underlying RCW cannot be used"
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is, but I suspect that its something along the lines of SP2 not supporting the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject 12.0` interop library.  Can anyone confirm my suspicion, or at least get me pointed in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: The solution is to update the office installation.  I also wouldn't target 4.0 if your trying to work with Office 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message tells you that there is an issue with the code accessing a COM instance that has been disposed of (via [`Marshal.ReleaseComObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) or [`Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx)). You should introduce **try/catch statements** to capture / log which section of the code is triggering this condition so you can resolve it.

Ideally you could get VS.NET debugging tools on the same machine that has this error so you could attach to the process before it occurs to pinpoint the source location.

Office can be very finicky when it comes to managing memory. You may just have to use good old trial and error to trap which section is failing.